# How many copy operations do Rust constructors perform?

Tags: constructor, copy, rust, copy-constructor

I have the following code:

```
struct SomeStruct {
    foo: i32
}

impl SomeStruct {
    fn new() -> SomeStruct {
        SomeStruct { foo: 42 }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let val = SomeStruct::new();
}
```

When one calls `SomeStruct::new()` how many copy operations are there? First, returning value was created on the stack of the `new` function. Is it copied right after it to the stack of the `main` function and the original one is destroyed due to leaving the scope (C++ behaviour)?

And a more general use case:

```
struct SomeResource {
    handle: i32  // For example, it's open file descriptor.
}

impl SomeResource {
    fn new() -> SomeResource {
        SomeResource { handle: 0 }
    }
}

struct SomeClient {
    r: SomeResource
}

impl SomeClient {
    fn new() -> SomeClient {
        SomeClient { r: SomeResource::new() }
    }
}

fn main() {
    SomeClient::new();
}
```

Is this a common way to create nested objects in Rust?

Comment: There are exactly `0` copy ops there :)

Comment: Constructors are no different from other functions - you may be interested in the terms "return value optimization" and "named return value optimization".